# Very slow connection between Power Bi and Spark Thrift Server Using Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, spark-thriftserver

I am using the "spark" connector in Power Bi desktop application to connect to spark thrift server using "HTTP" connection mode with "SSL" enabled and "Direct Query" option.

[image]

The connection went successfully however, there is a too long time latency approximately 10 minutes on every communication between Power Bi app and the Spark Thrift Server (e.g. authentication, loading meta-data, loading a specific table, ...etc). The source of the data is "Hive Server2".

My Spark Thrift Config in "hive-default.xml" is as follows:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>PAM</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.pam.services</name>
    <value>login,sudo,sshd</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.keystore.path</name>
    <value>************</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.keystore.password</name>
    <value>************</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
    <value>http</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
    <value>10001</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
     <value>cliservice</value>
</property>
```

Firstly, I suspected that the "SSL" encryption is slowing the communication and I disabled it but, the issue still persisted. Therefore, I concluded that it is irrelevant to this issue.

Any ideas regarding how to enhance communication speed?

Note: I tested to connect to the Spark Thrift server using "beeline" command line tool with "HTTP" mode enabled and "SSL" encryption and it went very fast, so I eliminated also any possibility of network latency issues.